# What is the Best Way to Make a Selection in a Dropdown Based on Several Possible Values

Tags: jquery, arrays, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome extension that lets you choose a size of an item and check out quickly.

I have a value called "Large" in sizePref array in my chrome.storage. And when it calls that value, it will choose an option in a dropdown based on that. However, possible labels are "Large", "L", "M/L" or "L/XL" ("Large" being the most often) with the  value changing each time.

What is the most efficient way for me to ensure that it makes the correct selection (assuming the speed of doing so is the highest priority)?

This is my current code which just chooses "L" if "Large" doesn't exist. This code works without errors, but I want it to be improved.

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('sizePref', function(items) { // Get size preferences from storage
        var sizePref = items.sizePref.top1; // Set size to a var

        var sizeVal = $("#size option").filter(function() {
            return $(this).html() == sizePref;
        }).val();

        var sizeVal2 = $("#size option").filter(function() {
            return $(this).html() == "L";
        }).val();



        if (sizeVal !== undefined) {
            $("#size").val(sizeVal);
        } else {
            $("#size").val(sizeVal2);
        }


    });
```

The targeted dropdown code is as follows

```
<select id="size" name="size"><option value="25243">Small</option>
<option value="25244">Medium</option>
<option value="25245">Large</option>
<option value="25246">XLarge</option></select>
```

Comment: First, you arent checking if the stored item is not there. Second, to qualify as a valid question please include what is the error or issue (apparently related to performance, how?) In the code you posted. Otherwise it will be flagged/downvoted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There isn't an issue. My code just doesn't seem efficient as it's filtering the size option several times. I just want it to be improved.

Comment: It would be more efficient if you didn't use jquery.

Comment: You'd better ask this question at http://ux.stackexchange.com/ (first search whether it has been asked before).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @RobW but I took a look at the forum and correct me if I'm wrong, the questions there seems more about layouts as opposed to what I'm looking for, which is about performance speed and coding best practice.

Comment: Ah, I mistakenly thought that you meant "the user" by "it", but you're actually referring to "the code". If you just want a code review, try http://codereview.stackexchange.com. That site is more suitable for asking about potential improvements to working code.

Answer (score 0):

you can improve it by not using filter. instead have a single for loop and assign the two variables there.
note that this kind of performance improvements will not have any visible impact on speed or memory usage unless you have thousands of list items.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If that's the case, then I guess its not necessary in my case. But it's always good to learn the best practice.

About your answer, how can I assign the variable if the option's value is random without using a filter?